# Editing (PUT) a record in MVC5/WebAPI2 results in error "Unable to serialize the session state."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-web-api, put

I have an MVC5 front end and a WebAPI version 2 back end.  When I go to edit a record on my front end, I make my form field changes and click "Save", I immediately get the error:

[image]

This error **ONLY** happens when I edit a record.  It works fine when creating a brand new record.

Here's my stack trace:

```
[SerializationException: Type 'AppTools.HelperClasses.LoggerHelper' in Assembly 'AppTools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +10494323
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +230
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +121
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +178
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +51
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +540
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +131
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1666

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and 'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects, and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.]
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +1754
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.WriteValueToStreamWithAssert(Object value, BinaryWriter writer) +34
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Serialize(BinaryWriter writer) +628
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.Serialize(SessionStateStoreData item, Stream stream) +240
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateUtility.SerializeStoreData(SessionStateStoreData item, Int32 initialStreamSize, Byte[]& buf, Int32& length, Boolean compressionEnabled) +62
   System.Web.SessionState.OutOfProcSessionStateStore.SetAndReleaseItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, SessionStateStoreData item, Object lockId, Boolean newItem) +111
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.OnReleaseState(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +798
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Here's my WebAPI `PUT` method:

```
        [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, BulletinBoard bulletinBoard)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }

            db.Entry(bulletinBoard).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

Here's my front end (MVC5) Edit Action method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, BulletinBoard bulletinBoard)
        {
            bulletinBoard.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            bulletinBoard.ModifiedBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;        

            response = client.PutAsJsonAsync(string.Format("api/bulletinboard/put/{0}", id), bulletinBoard).Result;
            //var test = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //HttpContext.Response.Write(test);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                LoggerHelper.GetLogger().InsertError(new Exception(string.Format(
                    "Cannot create a new message due to HTTP Response Status Code not being successful: {0}", response.StatusCode)));
                return View("Problem");
            }
        }
```

**Please help me understand why I'm getting this error!**

Comment: Where id comes?  I mean from Url or its part of post request

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat The ID comes from part of the URL.

Comment: btw you have [SerializationException: Type 'AppTools.HelperClasses.LoggerHelper' in Assembly 'AppTools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.] where LoggerHelper is used?

Comment: Look like you have action or some thing like on top of put

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat LoggerHelper simply inserts the exception into the error database.  I've never had to mark LoggerHelper as serializable before.  It catches and handles/inserts all other errors/exceptions without fault... it's only when I edit a record is when this problem happens.

Comment: Can you post how and where you are using it? because in error description it mentioned about that.

Comment: I have added possible answer

Answer (score 0):

probably issue is that you model is trying to update without id since since you have signature

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, BulletinBoard bulletinBoard)
```

So thats mean that bulletinBoard could have no setted id then you have

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
 }
```

then probably your model is invalid and response should return status Status Code:400 Bad Request, but since you have some where log exception which is not serializable then it throw exeption

to solve it try

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, BulletinBoard bulletinBoard) {
bulletinBoard.Id = id;
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it.  I will try to use Fiddler again.